# PHP 5.3.2 and Zend Framework Sessions

Tags: php, linux, apache, zend-framework

We recently upgraded our PHP and apache versions on our server.

Prior to this our sessions were able to be carried over between subdomains without error.

Unfortunately when we made the upgrades it stopped working.

From what I can see everything is the same.

I have tried 
ini_set("suhosin.session.cryptdocroot", "Off");
ini_set("suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot", "Off");

But that didn't work out.

I am already setting in my Bootstrap the cookie_domain to ".website.com".

Anybody have any ideas what could possibly have changed to make this great of an impact!?

Here's the code:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.com');

    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db_global');  
    $config = array(
        'name'           => '_sessions',
        'primary'        => 'id',
        'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
        'dataColumn'     => 'data',
        'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime',
        'customerIdColumn' => 'customer_id',
        'db' => $db   // db adapter
    );

    //I tried it with the typical savehandler and got the same result of not working
    Zend_Session::setSaveHandler(new Custom_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config));
    Zend_Session::start();
```

Comment: Any code for us? Ensure you set cookie_domain with Zend_Session before you start the session

Comment: Updated the code, from what I can see we're not doing anything wrong it appears to have happened during our upgrades of PHP and Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Zend_Session for the cookie_domain, best place is your bootstrap:

```
Zend_Session::start(array('cookie_domain' => '.domain.com'));
```

An other idea: New settings in php.ini `like session.auto_start = true` ?